# Azure solution for hosting TCP server

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-functions, azure-web-roles

Im looking for a way to host a scalable c# server and im thinking that Azure is a good fit. This is what i need to be able to do.
Be accessible by clients via static ip adrress
Use TCP communication
Receive serialised data from clients
Send serialised data to clients

I am open for non azure solutions as well but from what i have learned some type of azure solution should work great.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this. I am on a similar situation not able to determine where to host tcp listner in azure.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in the past using Worker Roles (Cloud Services). I do think it's deprecated nowadays so you should go with AKS or Azure Container Apps.